# How to Transform mongodb query using java code

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am new to MongoDB. I wanted to transform this mongo DB query to java code. I have tried a little bit. But I am having an issue. Please, If anybody helps means that will be a great help for me. Thanks in advance.

```js
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
  [{
      $match: {
        "ids": 9999999,
        $or : [{"tags.name":"roja"},{"tags.location":"US"},{"tags.year":2019}]
      }
    },
    {
      '$facet': {
        metadata: [{ $count: "total" }],
        data: [{
          $addFields: {
            "weight": {
              $map: {
                input: "$tags",
                as: "tagsEl",
                in: {
                  "$add": 
                    [              
                      {$cond: [ { $eq: [ '$$tagsEl.roja', 'roja' ] }, 15, 1 ]} ,
                      {$cond: [ { $eq: [ '$$tagsEl.location', 'US' ] }, 10, 1 ]},
                      {$cond: [ { $eq: [ '$$tagsEl.year', 2019 ] }, 5, 1 ]}                    
                    ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }, { $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 10 }, { '$sort': { 'weight' : -1 } }]
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Studio3T](https://studio3t.com/download/) to directly convert your query into java code, unless you don't get comfortable with the syntax.

https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/query-code/

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get database
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdb");

//get collection
MongoCollection<Document> testCol = db.getCollection("test");

//prepare a list of aggregation pipeline stages.
List<Bson> aggs = new ArrayList<>();

//each pipeline stage you wrote is in js. the equivalent java syntax is...

//for {key1:value1,key2:value2}
  new Document().append("key1","value1").append("key2","value2")

//for array such as ["abc",1,{key3,value3}]
  Arrays.asList("abc",1,new Document("key3","value3"))


//for example , part of your script can be implemented in java as below.
 aggs.add(
  new Document("$match",//match aggregation pipeline stage
    new Document("ids",9999999)
      .append("$or",Arrays.asList(
        new Document("tags.name","roja"),
        new Document("tags.location","US"),
        new Document("tags.year",2019)
       ))
  )
);
//you can add as many stages as you need to aggs list.
//execute
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = testCol.aggregate(aggs).iterator();
while(cursor.hasNext()){
  Document d = cursor.next();
  //do your operation.
}
```